# Exception without using velocity in Struts 2 while parsing struts.xml

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, velocity, struts-config

Here is my `struts.xml` file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>

<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" /> 
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory" />  

<package name="Authentiate" extends="struts-default">

<global-results>

<result name="error">/error.jsp</result>

</global-results>

<action name="loginAuthenticate*" class="com.authenticate.actions.LoginAuthenticate" method="{1}">

<result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>
<result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
<result name="redirectRegister" type="redirect">/registration.jsp</result>

</action>

</package>
```

I haven't used velocity templates but I am getting the following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=org.apache.struts2.views.velocity.VelocityManager, name='default'] in public void org.apache.struts2.osgi.OsgiConfigurationProvider.setVelocityManager(org.apache.struts2.views.velocity.VelocityManager). - Class: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder
```

Comment: What version of Struts2?

Comment: Are you using OSGi bundle? Maybe you have added too many jars ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to point result type explicitly using default type `dispatcher`:

```
<result name="success" type="dispatcher">/welcome.jsp</result>
<result name="error" type="dispatcher">/error.jsp</result>
<result name="redirectRegister" type="redirect">/registration.jsp</result>
```

If this doesn't help, it looks like there are some struts dependencies that can't be resolved. According to [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-2391) at apache's bugtracker you should add `VelocityManager` bean to your `struts.xml`:

```
<bean class="org.apache.struts2.views.velocity.VelocityManager" name="default" optional="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is *really* weird error. Fixed by removing [spring-struts](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/web-integration.html) jar from dependencies.

Velocity is not necessary to add as a dependency if you are not using velocity templates in your results. By default Struts2 uses Freemarker templates.

Errors may not seen if your server not utilizing JMX, but if you run in [JMX enabled appserver like JBOSS](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r2/html/ch2.chapter.html) it might raise.